# Best place to implement ko.applyBindings

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, typescript

I am using TypeScript and Knockout in my MVC project, in my .ts file i implemented viewmodel class and 2 more classes under module and i am also using jquery under $(document).ready.
Now my problem is i want to apply binding if i implement ko.applyBindings(viewModel) in one place under class it get set values but when i change my textbox and dropdown values its never sets b/c ko.applyBindings(viewModel) is not applying again.

Not sure where should i implement ko.applyBindings(viewModel), please give me idea or location where i will implement.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ko.applyBinding should be called once for the markup.

Thus if you have a page with some bindings like

```
<input data-bind="value: vmtext">
```

You can call ko.applyBinding at the bottom of the page or on the domready event anywhere.

Don't forget that to make two-ways bindings work you need ko.observable in vm like:

```
var vm = {
     vmtext: ko.observable("initial value")
};
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

If you will add some markup later during the work (e.g. load partial view markup asynchronously), you have to applyBindings on it too to make bindings work.